# ASP.net MVC Get entities where key is in an array/list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, list, ienumerable

I have a table(DbSet) called 'Submission' and a List(Of Integer) containing a selection of primary keys from the Submission table.

How do I filter down the DbSet to return an IENumerable(Of Submission) for all Submissions with a primary key in the List of integers?

If I wanted just one Submission I would do the following:

```
Dim db As New MyEntities
Dim result As Submission

result = db.Submission.Find(key)
Return result
```

What I actually need is something like this (obviously not using the code below though as it wont work):

```
Dim db As New MyEntities
Dim keys As List(Of Integer)
Dim results As IENumerable(Of Submission)

results = db.Submission.Find(keys)
Return results
```

Many thanks in advance for any assistance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the C# syntax, but:

```
result = db.Submission.Where(s => keys.Contains(s.Id));
```

Comment: Wow, how on earth did I miss that?!? Thank you so much!!